# QMetaObject::indexOfMethod returns an index in what exactly?

Tags: c++, qt, properties, metadata

To elaborate on the ambiguous title, I'd like to roughly know how the meta system works dynamically.

When working with slots/property accessors in a static context the calls are probably inlined, after all if it is possible why not??

But what about dynamic scenarios and querying for indices? How is the meta object implemented? Is the offset one of a pointer in a virtual table? Or maybe Qt creates its own vtable instead the one used by the class virtual methods? In this case, are virtual property methods duplicated in both the class "native" vtable as well as the hypothetical extra one created for the static meta object? Are the actual calls technically virtual?

I am not interest in intricate details, more like the overall concept.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no such thing as a "virtual table" when portable C++ is concerned. It's an implementation detail, hidden by the compiler. There's no way to portably access its internals (the implementation's data structure), only its semantics (the functionality it offers).

Secondly, you don't say what you mean by a "call". Assume we have

```
class BaseObject : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void mySignal();
}

class MyObject : public BaseObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_SLOT void mySlot();
};
MyObject myObject;
```

There are multiple ways of invoking `mySlot`.

1. Calling it directly:

   ```
   myObject.mySlot("yay!")
   ```

   This is no different than calling any other method - just because it's a slot, doesn't make it special from C++'s point of view. If it happens to be a virtual method, it's a virtual method call, with any overheads this entails on a given platform.
2. By using the virtual `qt_metacall` method with the method index:

   ```
   myObject.qt_metacall(QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, 4, nullptr);
   ```

   The implementation of `qt_metacall` is generated by moc. The `qt_metacall` **is where the method indices get defined**. Internally, `qt_metacall` calls itself recursively all the way into `QObject::qt_metacall`.

   Each implementation checks if the method index is less than the number of metamethods on this class. The constant data record with this information is generated by moc. For example, `QObject` has three metamethods - the two signals and one slot. If the index is too larger than 2, it is decremented by the number of metamethods and returned to the next derived class's `qt_metacall`.

   When `QObject::qt_metacall` returns into `BaseObject::qt_metacall`, the index has been decremented by 3, and is now one (4-3 = 1). Since `BaseObject` has only one metamethod (index 0), this index is decremented by one and returned.

   When `BaseObject::qt_metacall` returns into `MyObject::qt_metacall`, the index has been decremented by (3+1=4), and is now zero (0). That's the local index of the lone `mySlot`, and call is handled by passing the index to `MyObject::qt_static_metacall`.
3. By using the static `qt_static_metacall` (it's a private method, though):

   ```
   MyObject::qt_static_metacall(&myObject, QMetaObject::InvokeMethod, 0, nullptr);
   ```

   The `qt_static_metacall` is a static method that implements the actual call. It simply switches on the local, 0-based index, and calls the method, passing any arguments it needs. The pointers-to-arguments are passed in the last argument - here it's simply a `nullptr` since there are no arguments. This is plain boring C++ code, no magic there.

   We use the knowledge that the method with index 4 is really a method on `MyObject` (and not, say, `QObject` or `BaseObject`). Since all the base classes together use up 4 indices, we adjust the method index down by the same amount - to zero (4-4 = 0).

   So, if you know what concrete class implements the method index, you can call the static method directly without using the recursive virtual `qt_metacall`. This lookup is performed by `QObject::connect` when the connection is being set up. The connection's destination is stored as a local method index and a pointer to the `qt_static_metacall` method of the class that has given method. This saves the cost of recursion of `qt_metacall` when the slot is invoked by the connected signal.
4. By using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`:

   ```
   QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&myObject, "mySlot");
   ```

   This performs all the same lookups as `QObject::connect` does, but instead of setting up a connection, it executes the call right away. Again, it will end in `MyObject::qt_static_metacall`.
5. By using `QMetaMethod::invoke`:

   ```
   QMetaMethod method = myObject.metaObject()->method(
                          myObject.metaObject->indexOfSlot("mySlot()"));
   method.invoke(myObject);
   ```

   The `QMetaObject` caches the looked-up pointer to `MyObject::qt_static_metacall` as well as the local method index 0. Thus the `invoke` call has less overhead than the one from `QMetaObject`.